# Linux permissions on a remote mount

Tags: linux, permissions

On Windows, when I look at the permissions on a remote folder, the accounts are qualified with the machine name or domain, i.e. the authority for the account name.

On Linux, if I have a VM with a mount to a remote drive and the owner of a folder on the mount is 'root', then is that my root or the root of the remote system?

It all seems way too simple on Linux to work as soon as a network is involved. I'm clearly missing something.

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is, unfortunately, one of the most confusing things about file sharing on Unixes. And I'm bad at explaining confusing things.*

What you **see** in `ls -l` output (for example), is the remote user's ID translated from the perspective of the local system.

When programs like `ls` use the standard functions to look up file information, the filesystem driver can only provide them with numeric user IDs, not textual names. *(So far, not too different from Windows.)* To translate the UIDs to names, `ls` calls an entirely different OS component, the name service libraries, which have no knowledge about where that UID was obtained from, and therefore can only translate accounts that the operating system knows about, but cannot go back and ask the filesystem driver for help. *(This is where the difference comes in.)*

As an example, if the server has two files, one owned by root (UID 0), the other owned by Luke (UID 1000), `ls` will only know that they're owned by "0" and "1000", and will look for *local* accounts that have the same UIDs. "0" is always root, but "1000" may or may not be Luke. If the UID belongs to an account stored in LDAP or NIS or AD, and if the client OS is actually *configured* to look in LDAP for user accounts, it'll give the correct username. Otherwise it might actually lie, since local account UIDs (1000, 1001, ...) tend to correspond to different people on different computers.

(There are ways that the filesystem driver could tell programs the full user name, in the form of "extended attributes". Unfortunately, despite various attempts there is no standard way of doing that, and programs like `ls` generally try to avoid filesystem-specific tricks. Even more unfortunately, not all network filesystem protocols *can* transfer the user names: CIFS aka SMB can, NFSv4 can, most other ones cannot.)

*But none of that really matters,* since what you **can do** with the file is always determined by what the server knows, not by what the client sees. For example, if you use `sshfs`, it logs into the server over SSH using your username (e.g. `sshfs luke@fileserver`), and the server won't let you do anything that you're not supposed to do. The same with CIFS, AFS, and so on.

Comment: So it could show a completely wrong owner if the UID of the real owner matches a UID I have locally? Seriously? Without any data stored for the 'issuing authority' of the UID, how does the server differentiate two local user accounts with the same UID?

Comment: @LukePuplett: Yes, it would. If the server says "this file is owned by UID 1000", the client will show what the _client_ knows by that UID. And, once again, the server _doesn't have to_ differentiate. With CIFS or SSHFS or AFS, the server doesn't _care_ about client UIDs, simply because the client could _lie_. The server only cares about secure credentials like password or Kerberos ticket that you present. (Same with Windows. Network file access in Windows uses either Kerberos or NTLM with your username & password; it does not use SIDs, with 'authority' prefix or without.)

Comment: @LukePuplett: Of course, there are exceptions. NFS doesn't have "password" authentication; if you can't do Kerberos, then auth-by-UID is the only remaining method (the client says "UID 1000 is trying to access this file", and the server believes that). In this situation, when there's a possibility of UIDs mismatching, or the client being able to spoof UIDs, the only choice is to not use NFS in the first place. But again, this is an exception. Other protocols (like CIFS, or NFS with Kerberos), do not care about local UIDs at all.

Comment: @LukePuplett: Also keep in mind that there are many cases when the "issuing authority" cannot be trusted. Imagine a Windows image cloned to a dozen computers and sold to different customers. Now you have all of them having different accounts with the same SID _including_ the authority part. [And here's Microsoft saying it doesn't matter.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx) Therefore, lack of authority in Unix UIDs doesn't matter either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. FWIW Windows only uses SIDs, the username and password just prove the authorised account holder on login.

The username is not stored in ACEs, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961995.aspx

Take two cloned Windows PCs, having the same machine SID. From PC1, give Administrator permissions to a file on USB, then place it in PC2 and its Administrator will get access because the SID is the same.

I don't understand Linux/Unix at all, but the absence of an authority element looks like a strange design.

Comment: @LukePuplett: Yes, the ACEs only have SIDs, and that **does not change a thing** about what I wrote. You seem to be implying that the client starts by saying "user X wants to log in", but afterwards uses "someone with sid Y wants to open a file". This is wrong; the client never sends any SID to the server, because the server would not trust it anyway. You connect to a file server, authenticate as user Y, the server looks up the SID of user Y, and always matches that SID and only that SID against the ACEs.

Comment: @LukePuplett: Your cloned Windows PC example also _contradicts_ your own complaint that "the absence of an authority element [in Unix] looks like a strange design", because you demonstrate yourself that such an authority element would be _meaningless_ in practice.

Comment: @LukePuplett: From your "strange design" comment, it seems that you think Windows added the UID/SID authority element first, and Unix/Linux decided against including it later. It's the opposite. Windows NT was started in 1993 with domains and file sharing in mind, while Unix dates back to early 1970's and didn't even have network support for quite a while.

Comment: I know how Kerberos works, I worked for Microsoft as a Windows NT engineer. The Authority ID is not "meaningless", it prevents the ID collision issues we're discussing. Finally, its a strange design in that its got issues and no-one decided to improve it. Apple have/are: "OS X has similarly incorporated other technologies from Microsoft's Windows, including support for Windows-style ACLs, a more robust and fine-grained system for implementing file-based permissions that offered a variety of improvements over the existing BSD Unix-style permissions used in prior versions of OS X."

Comment: Saying its meaningless is like saying football teams wearing different coloured shirts is meaningless because some player could put a cloned shirt on. Well, yes, but that possibility doesn't mean coloured shirts has no merit, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The owner is the root user on the remote machine. If you want to have access to it as root on the remote machine you'll have to mount it as root on the remote machine.

In other words, this should work (local user aye, remote user root):

```
aye@ayes-machine$ sshfs root@bees-machine:/path /local-path
```

This won't work (local user root, remote user bee):

```
aye@ayes-machine$ sudo sshfs bee@bees-machine:/path /local-path
```